# Cannot Resolve import com.google.android.gms

Tags: android, gradle, libgdx, google-play-services, google-play-games

I made a game with using Libgdx library. Now I want to add a leader board table to my game. For doing this I followed this tutorial : [here](https://www.versionpb.com/tutorials/step-step-tutorials-libgdx-basic-setup-libgdx/implementing-google-play-services-leaderboards-in-libgdx/)

But in that tutorial I stuck at step 29. Because my imports doesn't resolved.

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games.GamesOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.games.GamesActivityResultCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Invitation;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.Multiplayer;
import com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.turnbased.TurnBasedMatch;
import com.google.android.gms.games.request.GameRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus.PlusOptions;
```

For example , After I write `import com.google.android.gms.games` and write `.` , only two hints show up to me : `R` and `*`.

In sdk manager , Google Play Services has already installed.(I use Android Studio)

Also,It is my projects build.gradle for Android :

```
   project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:15.0.1"// I think this line should solve all imports problem, but it can't
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0"
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'

        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

    }
}
```

What can I do for solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you have `play-services-auth` but with two different versions? thats a problem. Also why if you are declaring `play-services:+` are you using specific parts of the google play services libraries, thats another problem

Comment: @tyczj Because , while I searching my problem , I added all solutions types to my gradle for making it guarantee.

Comment: well what you are doing is causing conflicts and incorrect, you are using old versions of google play services and should read how to import google play services properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are lacking the `play-services-base` library:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.5.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:21.0.0"
```

... as well as, having added `play-services-auth` twice, for whatever reason. and also `play-services:+` does not appear to be correct and therefore should also be removed. with the new versioning, one has to add these dependencies individually.

Comment: thanks a lot , I tried with your first solution and synch it but there is nothing change, after that I think that closing and re opening the Android Studio and it is work :) thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the build.gradle file inside your application module directory.
2. Add a new build rule under dependencies for the latest version of
   play-services.
3. Ensure that your top-level build.gradle contains a reference to the
   google() repo or to maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }.
4. Save the changes, and click **Sync Project with Gradle Files** in the
   toolbar.

[image]